# Script and Rmarkdown taking too long to run certain functions

Tags: r, database, dataframe

I am working on an analysis of bicycle data for a google course that I am wrapping up.

I coded the entire analysis in an R script editor, and it runs fine. It takes a bit of time because the csv datasets I am working with are quite large. In Rmarkdown, I am getting stuck at a specific function. My code goes as follows-

````
---
title: "Cyclistic_Case_Study"
author: "mark"
date: "2/24/2022"
output: html_document

---

## Setting up my environnment

Note: Loading 'tidyverse', 'lubridate' and 'dplyr' packages.

```{r loading packages}
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
````

### Loading Cyclistic Data and binding it into one dataframe

```
jan_2021 <- fread("C:\\Users\\mgian\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Case Study - Bikes\\jan_2021.csv")
feb_2021 <- fread("C:\\Users\\mgian\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Case Study - Bikes\\feb_2021.csv")
mar_2021 <- fread("C:\\Users\\mgian\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Case Study - Bikes\\march_2021.csv")
apr_2021 <- fread("C:\\Users\\mgian\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Case Study - Bikes\\april_2021.csv") 
may_2021 <-  fread("C:\\Users\\mgian\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Case Study - Bikes\\may_2021.csv")
june_2021 <-  fread("C:\\Users\\mgian\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Case Study - Bikes\\202106-divvy-tripdata.csv")
july_2021 <-  fread("C:\\Users\\mgian\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Case Study - Bikes\\july_2021.csv")
aug_2021 <-  fread("C:\\Users\\mgian\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Case Study - Bikes\\august_2021.csv")
sep_2021 <-  fread("C:\\Users\\mgian\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Case Study - Bikes\\sep_2021.csv")
oct_2021 <-  fread("C:\\Users\\mgian\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Case Study - Bikes\\oct_2021.csv")
nov_2021 <-  fread("C:\\Users\\mgian\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Case Study - Bikes\\nov_2021.csv")
dec_2021 <-  fread("C:\\Users\\mgian\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Case Study - Bikes\\dec_2021.csv")

cyclistic_2021 <- rbind(jan_2021, feb_2021, mar_2021, apr_2021, may_2021, june_2021, july_2021, aug_2021, sep_2021, oct_2021, nov_2021, dec_2021 )

View(cyclistic_2021)
```

### Preview of dataset with dput()

```
 preview <- cyclistic_2021 %>% head(10) %>% dput()

structure(list(ride_id = c("E19E6F1B8D4C42ED", "DC88F20C2C55F27F", 
"EC45C94683FE3F27", "4FA453A75AE377DB", "BE5E8EB4E7263A0B", "5D8969F88C773979", 
"09275CC10F854E9E", "DF7A32A217AEFB14", "C2EFC62379EB716C", "B9F73448DFBE0D45"
), rideable_type = c("electric_bike", "electric_bike", "electric_bike", 
"electric_bike", "electric_bike", "electric_bike", "electric_bike", 
"electric_bike", "electric_bike", "classic_bike"), started_at = structure(c(1611418459, 
1611772988, 1611268554, 1610026273, 1611368642, 1610202247, 1609736704, 
1610636820, 1610186275, 1611515738), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), ended_at = structure(c(1611419084, 1611773232, 
1611268634, 1610026975, 1611368685, 1610205474, 1609737039, 1610637220, 
1610186426, 1611516171), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    start_station_name = c("California Ave & Cortez St", "California Ave & Cortez St", 
    "California Ave & Cortez St", "California Ave & Cortez St", 
    "California Ave & Cortez St", "California Ave & Cortez St", 
    "California Ave & Cortez St", "California Ave & Cortez St", 
    "California Ave & Cortez St", "California Ave & Cortez St"
    ), start_station_id = c("17660", "17660", "17660", "17660", 
    "17660", "17660", "17660", "17660", "17660", "17660"), end_station_name = c("", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Wood St & Augusta Blvd"), 
    end_station_id = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "657"
    ), start_lat = c(41.9003406666667, 41.9003328333333, 41.9003126666667, 
    41.9003986666667, 41.9003263333333, 41.9004086666667, 41.9003905, 
    41.9003895, 41.9003058333333, 41.900363), start_lng = c(-87.696743, 
    -87.696707, -87.6966426666667, -87.6966621666667, -87.6966971666667, 
    -87.6967628333333, -87.6967573333333, -87.6967283333333, 
    -87.6967963333333, -87.696704), end_lat = c(41.89, 41.9, 
    41.9, 41.92, 41.9, 41.94, 41.9, 41.91, 41.9, 41.899181), 
    end_lng = c(-87.72, -87.69, -87.7, -87.69, -87.7, -87.71, 
    -87.71, -87.7, -87.7, -87.6722), member_casual = c("member", 
    "member", "member", "member", "casual", "casual", "member", 
    "member", "member", "member")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000025087cc1ef0>)
```

### Separating date and time columns.

```
cyclistic_2021 <- separate(cyclistic_2021, started_at, into=c('date','start_time'), sep = ' ')
cyclistic_2021 <- separate(cyclistic_2021, ended_at, into=c('ended_at','end_time'), sep = ' ')
```

At this point where I'm separating columns R becomes extremely slow. It will eventually load in the script, but I haven't got it to run in the rmarkdown successfully. I am wondering if there is a way to improve the speed or if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: How many rows is `cyclistic_2021`? Can you give a sample of `select(cyclistic_2021, started_at, ended_at) %>% head(10) %>% dput()` to create a reproducible sample of what the data looks like before the separate step?  (Please put the output into the original question.)

Comment: By the way, why separate the datetime fields into date and time parts? You can run date or time methods with full datetimes.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible dataset by providing the `dput` or subset of your data. Here is a guide for doing so: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 1):

While your question on performance is general, consider some particular guidelines:

- Keep with one flavor (base R for data.frames, tidyverse for tibbles, or data.table for data.tables) for all or most operations which can avoid costly, internal casting between methods of different flavors.

  Since [**`fread`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.2/topics/fread) by default returns data.table, consider sticking with this flavor which is known to be fast with very large datasets. Also, `data.table` maintains many fast procedures for cleaning and calculating such as [**`tstrsplit`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.2/topics/tstrsplit) to split text within columns.
- Minimize conversions and cleaning by exhausting all options in earlier called methods. For instance, use the useful arguments of `fread` which can `select` only needed columns or `drop` unneeded ones and `colClasses` to explicitly assign appropriate types, useful for datetime fields.
- Keep your resources low such as releasing large helper objects like all those 12 monthly CSVs with `rm` and explicitly calling, `gc()`. Alternatively, as demonstrated below releasing a *single* list of data.tables!

  Likely with RMarkdown unlike the R script, you are running the chunks interactively in RStudio. Therefore, try keeping your environment as minimalist to only the objects needed for your markdown. If needed, you can automate RMarkdown at command line to run all chunks outside RStudio with [**`rmarkdown::render()`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rmarkdown/versions/0.5.1/topics/render): `Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('mymarkdown.Rmd')"`.

Adjusted code

```r
# OS-AGNOSTIC PATHS
bike_dir <- file.path(
    "C:", "Users", "mgian", "OneDrive", "Documents", "Case Study - Bikes"
)
bike_files <- c(
    "jan_2021.csv", "feb_2021.csv", "march_2021.csv", 
    "april_2021.csv", "may_2021.csv", "202106-divvy-tripdata.csv",
    "july_2021.csv", "august_2021.csv", "sep_2021.csv", 
    "oct_2021.csv", "nov_2021.csv", "dec_2021.csv"
)

# BUILD LIST OF DATA TABLES
bike_dts <- lapply(
    bike_files, function(f) fread(file.path(bike_dir, f), select = ..., colClasses = ...)
)

# COMPILE INTO SINGLE DATA TABLE
cyclistic_2021 <- rbindlist(bike_dts)

# RELEASE LARGE OBJECT FROM ENVIRONMENT AND MEMORY
rm(bike_dir, bike_files, bike_dts)
invisible(gc())

# SPLIT COLUMNS (ASSUMING *_at ARE CHARACTER COLUMNS)
cyclistic_2021[, c('date','start_time') := tstrsplit(started_at, "\\s+", fixed=TRUE)]
cyclistic_2021[, c('ended_at','end_time') := tstrsplit(ended_at, "\\s+", fixed=TRUE)]

# OTHER data.table METHODS AND HANDLING
...
```